# Spresenseをできる限り消費電力にしたく、LTEボードのhibernationモード

Tags: spresense

消費電力にするために、できるだけSpresenseをスリープ（cold sleep）させます。
LTE通信を省電力するために、長いedrx_cycleを設定しています。

lte_hibernationというサンプルにはlte_enter_hibernationとlte_resume_from_hibernationという関数があって、Spresenseがスリープしている間、LTEボードもスリープさせます。Cold sleepではおそらくLTEボードの電源が落ち、コンテキストが無くなります。そのために、コンテキストをフラッシュにに保存し、起動後、再読み込みします。

問題は、「Sleep failed.」というエラーになっています。調べた限り、私のLTEボード（RK_02_01_02_10_108_54）はhibernationをサポートしていません。

/opt/spresense/spresense/sdk/apps/lte/alt1250/alt1250_devevent.c

```
if (IS_PV1_FIRMWARE(dev))
  {
    dbg_alt1250("This firmware doesn't support hibernation mode.\n");
    ret = ERROR;
    goto exit;
  }
```

Arduino SDKとSpresense SDKを両方使用しています。必要に応じで、カスタムArduino SDKを作成しています。
最終的にバッテリーとソーラーパネルで稼働したいです。接近センサーによって起動し、カメラで写真を取り、アップしようと考えています。

どのようにできる限り消費電力したらいいですか？
Cold Sleepに入ったら、どうしてもLTEのAttachをゼロからしなければなりませんか？20秒前後もかかります。